# How to load 8 32bit signed integers from unaligned memory into a __mm256i vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, simd, avx

My CPU doesn't support AVX512 so unfortunately I can't use the function `_mm256_loadu_epi32()`.

It looks like I can use "_mm256_set_epi32()", but I'm not sure if it's hopelessly slower than "_mm256_loadu_XXXXXX()". Any idea? what's the best way to do this?

Comment: It suggested using _mm256_loadu_si256() which "Load 256-bits of integer data". I'm not sure about if 256-bits of integer data will be treated like 8 signed int32, guess I will test it.

Comment: What is the epi32 version adding that the AVX `_mm256_loadu_si256 ` doesn't do? I see it is `vmovdqu32 ymm, m256` vs `vmovdqu ymm, m256` but the documentation looks basically the same.

Comment: @rustyx Thanks for pointing to it, it's definitely helpful! solved now

Comment: @FireLancer Yeah I understand it now. It was just a bit unintuitive to switch from the function to loading float/double to loading integer.